# How to change View while we touch any annotation

Tags: iphone, uiview, annotations, location, mkmapview

I want to add a functionality in MKMapView .

I have a mapView with many annotations now I want that .. when I touch any annotation the whole view should be focus on that annotation . i.e. annotation A is in the upper right corner and when I touch that the MapView should show that A in the centre then .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Annotation Delegate you have to set the Region for mapview specifying the center

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
   MKAnnotation *annotation= view.annotation;  // Get your annotaion here
   MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
   region.center.latitude=annotation.coordinate.latitude;
   region.center.longitude=annotation.coordinate.longitude;
   region.span.latitudeDelta=0.001f;
   region.span.longitudeDelta=0.001f;
   [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
  //Do your other stuffs here
}
```

Comment: @whySoSerious... I dont want it to zoom in so much ...Infect, not any zoom in... just it should be center that annotation . how to do that?

Comment: When setting the region the map will move to the location which we gave as center. Just try the thing which i gave

Comment: yes i tried .. but when I touch any location it is zooming in too much on that location ... so :( ..

Comment: just adjust the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta value so that it wont zoom and it will move to the center.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
   MKAnnotation *annotation= view.annotation;  // Get your annotaion here
   [map setCenterCoordinate:annotation.coordinate];  
}

//This will set the annotation in the centre of the map without zooming the map.
```